# How do I pause a HTML Audio IF div is display: none?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dom

I have an audio file in the header:

```
<audio controls autoplay> 
                         <source src="###" type="audio/ogg" />
                         <source src="###" type="audio/mpeg" />
                        </audio>
```

This is inside a DIV that is visible for desktop and tablets, but hidden on mobile. Apparently, this div loads even though I set it to display none and audio plays on mobile regardless the player not being visible. How do I make sure the audio doesnt start to play while the div is hidden and on desktop that the same div shows, the audio continues to play?

Comment: Better would be to not add the audio element at all for mobile so the audio is never loaded. Ain't that an option for you?

Comment: Apparently, the header loads regardless i've set it to hide on mobile.

Answer (score 0):

Calling the pause function when the div is hidden should do the trick.

```js
var wrapper = document.querySelector('#yourdiv');
var styles = window.getComputedStyle(wrapper);

if(styles.getPropertyValue('visibility') === 'hidden') {
  console.log('pausing');
  wrapper.querySelector('audio').pause();
}
```

```css
#yourdiv {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id='yourdiv'>
  hidden
  <audio></audio>
</div>
```